# Create random.randint with condition in a group by?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column called: `cars` and want to create another called `persons` using `random.randint()` which i have:

```
dat['persons']=np.random.randint(1,5,len(dat))
```

This is so I can put the number of persons who use these but I'd
like to know how to put a condition so in the `suv` category will be generated only numbers from 4 to 9 for example.

```
cars | persons
suv     4
sedan   2
truck   2         
suv     1      
suv     5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an index for your series, where matching rows have `True`, and everything else has `False`. You can then assign to the rows matching that index using [`loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to select the rows; you then generate just the number of values for those selected rows:

```
m = dat['cars'] == 'suv'
dat.loc[m, 'persons'] = np.random.randint(4, 9, m.sum())
```

You could also use `apply` on the `cars` series to create the new column, creating a new random value in each call:

```
dat['persons'] = dat.cars.apply(
    lambda c: random.randint(4, 9) if c == 'suv' else random.randint(1, 5))
```

But this has to make a separate function call for each row. Using a mask will be more efficient.

Comment: This should give context as to why: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
So, you're generating random numbers between 1 and 5, whereas numbers in the SUV category should be between 4 and 9. That just means you can generate a random number, and then add 4 to all random numbers belonging to the SUV category?

```
df = df.assign(persons=np.random.randint(1,5, len(df)))
df.loc[df.cars == 'suv', 'persons'] += 4

df

    cars  persons
0    suv        7
1  sedan        3
2  truck        1
3    suv        8
4    suv        8
```

---

**Option 2**
Another alternative would be using `np.where` -

```
df.persons = np.where(df.cars == 'suv', 
                      np.random.randint(5, 9, len(df)), 
                      np.random.randint(1, 5, len(df)))
df

    cars  persons
0    suv        8
1  sedan        1
2  truck        2
3    suv        5
4    suv        6
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to do this with something like a groupby that's more clever than I am, but my approach would be to build a function and apply it to your cars column. This is pretty flexible - it will be easy to build in more complicated logic if you want something different for each car:

```
def get_persons(car):
    if car == 'suv':
        return np.random.randint(4, 9)
    else:
        return np.random.randint(1, 5)
dat['persons'] = dat['cars'].apply(get_persons)
```

or in a more slick, but less flexible way:

```
dat['persons'] = dat['cars'].apply(lambda car: np.random.randint(4, 9) if car == 'suv' else np.random.randint(1, 5))
```

Comment: this is going to be much slower than the other solution

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. I'll describe what I did generally because application may vary. For smaller frames it won't matter so the above methods might work but for larger frames like mine (i.e.; hundreds of thousands to millions of rows) I would do this:

1. Sort `dat` by `'cars'`
2. Get a unique `list` of cars
3. Create a temporary `list` for the random numbers
4. Loop over that `list` of cars and populate the temporary `list` of random
   numbers and extending a new list with the temp list
5. Add the new list to the `'persons'` column
6. If order matters maintain and re-sort by the index