# Using groupby to speed up random number generation in part of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a program that uses a mask similar to the check marked answer shown here to create multiple sets of random numbers in a dataframe, `df`.

[Create random.randint with condition in a group by?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995898/create-random-randint-with-condition-in-a-group-by)

My code:

```
for city in state:
    mask = df['City'] == city
    df.loc[mask, 'Random'] = np.random.randint(1, 200, mask.sum())
```

This takes quite some time the bigger dataframe `df` is. Is there a way to speed this up with groupby?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of input and output.

Comment: How does doing this by group affect the outcome in any way?

Comment: I’ve used groupby in the past to replace masks in loops and it’s significantly improved performance. I don’t know if it will improve it or not, all I can do is try but I was unsure how in this instance. ‍♂️

Comment: How does randomly assigning a number between 1 and 200 to each row change if you do it in groups instead of on the entire dataframe?

Comment: I don’t know. All I know is I’ve used groupby in the past to apply other functions to subsets of dataframes instead of looping through masks and I didn’t know how to do it here.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing either. Both are pointless for your problem. You have broken up an operation that does not need to be grouped.

Comment: All I wanted to know was if there was a way to use groupby to speed this up and remove the loop. That’s it. Someone has answered and I’ll try that. If someone else answers something different, I’ll try that. I realize you’re focused on that 200. I was just trying to simplify things. Thats actually a variable length that is based on the group, so yes, it does need to be grouped. I was just trying to focus the question. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: CJR, although Corralien's way is quicker than my original, I did find an even quicker way, and... I don't know if maybe this is what you were alluding to? If it is, I gladly fall on my sword. I'll add a general answer in case anyone is looking for something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
df['Random'] = df.assign(Random=0).groupby(df['City'])['Random'] \
                 .transform(lambda x: np.random.randint(1, 200, len(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a much quicker way to do this. I'll keep it more general given the application might be different depending on what you want to achieve and keep Corralien's answer as the check mark.

Instead of creating a mask or group and using `.loc` to update the dataframe in place, I ***sorted*** the dataframe by the `'City'` then created a list of unique values from my `'City'` column.

Looping over the unique list (i.e.; the grouping), I generated the random numbers for each grouping, putting them in a new list using the `.extend()` function. I then added the 'Random' column from this list, and sorted the dataframe back using the index.